# Android VideoViev - Can't play this video (ARM CPU)

Tags: android, android-videoview

I did the straight application with the video file. On Intel's CPU everything is working (Dell Venue 7). But when I will start the application on ARM-based-cpu devie (HTC One S z520e or Asus Google Nexus 7 2013) I receive the announcement "Can't play this video". How I can solve this problem? Propeties of my video: mp4, 320x480, 500Kbps, 30FPS

XML:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

JAVA:
     public class Intro extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);
    VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.video/raw/video");
    vv.setVideoURI(uri);
    //vv.setVideoPath("/sdcard/video.mp4");
    vv.start();
    }
 }
```

Comment: U can use surfaceView for playing video

Comment: In some device video view is not working